# Access individual elements of List(POJOs) in jsp using <jsp:Usebean>

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a servlet which uses Hibernate and retrieves "Products" table from my DB.

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
    Transaction tx = null; 

   tx= session.beginTransaction();
   Query query=session.createQuery("from Products");
    List mylist1=query.list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    HttpSession httpSession=request.getSession();
    httpSession.setAttribute("Products", mylist1);

    RequestDispatcher dispacther=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispacther.forward(request, response);
```

I have forwarded the List of Products(pojo) to my jsp.
My question is how to retrieve individual elements of List and access them using `<jsp:useBean>` in my jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `<jsp:useBean>` thing at all. You're already using a servlet to manage the model. The model is already directly available in JSP via EL expression `${Products}` (although you'd better rename the thing to `products`, exactly following standard Java variable naming conventions).

```
httpSession.setAttribute("products", mylist1);
```

You can obtain the invididual elements by explicitly specifying their index using the brace notation:

```
${products[0]}
${products[1]}
${products[2]}
...
```

Or, better, just loop over them using [JSTL's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    ${product}
</c:forEach>
```

Your next question shall probably be "How do I print the properties of each individual product in tabular format?". Well, just put the `<c:forEach>` in a HTML `<table><tr><td>` and reference the properties in `${bean.propertyname}` format. Assuming that your `Product` has `id`, `name`, `description` and `price` properties, here's how it could look like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.id}</td>
            <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${product.description}" /></td>
            <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - explains about servlets and also demonstrates exactly your use case
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) - explains about JSTL
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) - explains about EL

Comment: Just an addition to this nice and detailed answer. If `Product` contains lazy loaded associations, it will break when you will try to get them in the JSP because Hibernate session will be closed. Force eager loading in this use case (using JOIN in request if mapping proposes lazy).